# Strange C# property definition(indexer)

Tags: c#, properties

How is this different from a normal property in C#?

```
    public new Point3D this[int index]
    {
        get { return base[index]; }
        set
        {
            base[index] = value;
            CollectionModified();
        }
```

Comment: This is called an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an *indexer*; instead of being used as `obj.Foo`, it is used as `obj[index]`, i.e.:

```
var oldVal = obj[1];
obj[1] = newVal;
```

It is "different" because:

- it has no explicit name
- it accepts a parameter (or parameters)

note that the indexer parameters do not have to be integers; the can be all sorts:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> lookup = ...
string employeeKey = "000006";
decimal salary = lookup[employeeKey];
```

Comment: So, like having a dictionary of objects instead of having to explicitly make one yourself?

Comment: @EbiDK no, not at all; all it describes is something that *can be accessed by index*; what that *means* is up to the implementaion. In this case, as dasblinkenlight observes, it is using the base-classes definition of what indexer access means, most likely a "list". It absolutely doesn't create any kind of dictionary; I was using the dictionary as an example of something else *that can be accessed via an indexer*.

Answer (score 2):

It is an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). It works like this (No need to call any property):

```
yourPoints[0] = new Point3D();

Point3D point = yourPoints[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an *indexer property*, a kind of property that lets your custom class participate in expressions that pass array subscripts in square brackets.

This indexer replaces an indexer property of its base class (likely, a collection), which must also have an indexer property. The getter forwards the call to the base, while the setter also calls `CollectionModified`, presumably to notify whomever is watching for modifications in the collection.

Comment: Pedantic, but that doesn't *override* - it *re-declares* (method-hiding).

Comment: indeed, I already edited :) It would be significantly better if it *did* `override` rather than `new` - because it is very unlikely that this version is being used in all scenarios (`IList`, for example)